# Basic Regular Expression for a 'generic' phone number

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, validation

I need a regex (for use in an ASP .NET web site) to validate telephone numbers. Its supposed to be flexible and the only restrictions are:

- should be at least 9 digits
- no alphabetic letters
- can include Spaces, hyphens, a single (+)

I have searched SO and Regexlib.com but i get expressions with more restrictions e.g. UK telephone or US etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's best to ask the user to fill in his country, then apply a regex for that country. Every country has its own format for phone numbers.

Comment: Exactly right - there is no standard, so it's difficult to provide a regex that will match across the board without making it so generic that it can't prevent invalid entries.

Comment: I wanted a flexible format. Here (SA) there is no strict phone format (e.g 0711231234, 071 123 1234, 071-123-1234, (071) 123 1234 are acceptable). I guess a masked edit box is the best way forward.

Comment: In that case, I suppose a regex that would accept exactly 10 digits and filtered out (, ), and whitespace would do.

Answer (score 21):

```
^\s*\+?\s*([0-9][\s-]*){9,}$
```

Break it down:

```
^           # Start of the string
  \s*       # Ignore leading whitespace
  \+?       # An optional plus
  \s*       # followed by an optional space or multiple spaces
  (
     [0-9]  # A digit
     [\s-]* # followed by an optional space or dash or more than one of those
  )
   {9,}     # That appears nine or more times
$           # End of the string
```

I prefer writing regexes the latter way, because it is easier to read and modify in the future; most languages have a flag that needs to be set for that, e.g. `RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace` in C#.

Comment: Note that this is a very lax approach; it would accept numbers like `+--1---2345 - - - 678  9 - `, and only checks that there's a minimum of nine digits and that a plus only appears at the start. I think that's what you wanted though.

Answer (score 5):

`\+?[\d- ]{9,}`

This will match numbers optionally starting with a plus and then at least nine characters long with dashes and spaces.

Although this means that dashes and spaces count towards the nine characters.
I would remove the dashes and spaces and then just use

`\+?[\d]{9,}`

Answer (score 2):

> ^[0-9-+ ]+$

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator runat="server" id="rgfvphone" controltovalidate="[control id]" validationexpression="^[0-9-+ ]+$" errormessage="Please enter valid phone!" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@"^(?:\+?1[-. ]?)?\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$"
```

Here's what I use. This will handle generic phone number validation for most cases.

Answer (score 0):

This one is super-generic, allowing only the characters you expect in a given phone number, including #. It ignores any format patterns.

```
@"^([\(\)\+0-9\s\-\#]+)$"
```