# Telephone number validation

Tags: c#

I have this code to validate a phone number but it looks a bit awkward.  I'm guessing theres a better way to go about this. How can I make this more efficient?

```
public static bool validTelephoneNo(string telNo)
{
    bool condition = false;
    while (condition == false)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a phone number.");
        telNo = Console.ReadLine();
        if (telNo.Length > 8)
        {
            if (telNo.StartsWith("+") == true)
            {
                char[] arr = telNo.ToCharArray();
                for (int a = 1; a < telNo.Length; a++)
                {
                    int temp;

                    try
                    {
                        temp = arr[a];
                    }

                    catch
                    {
                        break;
                    }

                    if (a == telNo.Length - 1)
                    {
                        condition = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Would be better in [CodeReview.SE] in my opinion..

Comment: what makes a telephone number valid?

Comment: consists of integers, is less than 8 digits in length and has a plus at the start

Comment: what is the valid format of telefone number? Use Regular expression.

Comment: Refer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18091324/regex-to-match-all-us-phone-number-formats

Comment: any format as long as it meets the requirements above

Comment: This code doesn't appear to work.  There is no possible way to return `false`.  All phone numbers will be validated, right?  If this is the case, this question *would not* be a good fit for [codereview.se], @SonerGönül Code that does not work is off-topic for [codereview.se].

Comment: possible duplicate of [Basic Regular Expression for a 'generic' phone number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6330399/basic-regular-expression-for-a-generic-phone-number)

Comment: I think its more than 8 characters will also work Check that if condition inside loop

Comment: @Sayse Oh, I missed the `u`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your goal can be easily achieved using regular expressions:

```
public static bool validTelephoneNo(string telNo)
{
    return Regex.Match(telNo, @"^\+\d{1,7}$").Success;
}
```

This pattern is exactly as stated: *consists of integers, is less than 8 digits in length and has a plus at the start*, and also this pattern can be modified if conditions somehow more complex.

Answer (score 6):

Don't try and do this yourself, use a library where someone has already done the hard work for you, such as [libphonenumber](https://libphonenumber.codeplex.com/).

Example:

```
public static bool validTelephoneNo(string telNo)
{
    PhoneNumber number;
    try
    {
        number = PhoneNumberUtil.Instance.Parse(telNo, "US");  // Change to your default language, international numbers will still be recognised.
    }
    catch (NumberParseException e)
    {
        return false;
    }

    return number.IsValidNumber;
}
```

This library will handle parsing and formatting phone numbers from different countries.  Not only will this ensure that the number is valid in the relevant country, it will also allow you to filter out premium numbers and "fake" numbers (such as 555 in the US).

Comment: Hi @Richard,
I want to use the libphonenumber library in a c# plugin for dynamics. However, using MSILMerge this doesn't seem to work, since it's a weakly signed assembly. I also tried using BrutalDev Strong signer to get around the weak signing. But, then I get the error "Could not find reference: PhoneNumbers, ..."
Any clue how to make this work?

Comment: I made another thread around this, hopefully you can help me out on this one
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71321559/how-to-use-google-lib-phonenumbers-in-dynamics-c-sharp-plugin

Answer (score 3):

try

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter a phone number.");
bool isValid = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"^[+]\d{1,7}$").IsMatch(Console.ReadLine());
```

Where the regex checks whether there is only a single number (1 to 7 digits) with `+` in front of them read. The drawback, this way you cannot further processed, you might need to read the line from console to a new variable.