# How to use google lib-phonenumbers in dynamics c# plugin

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, nuget-package, libphonenumber

For validating and formatting phone numbers with a plugin, I'd like to use google's libphonenumber-csharp package. When I download this in the NuGet Package Manager, I first get the error that the package is not strongly signed (which is the case). Once I use for example BrutalDev strong signer, to ensure the package is strongly signed, or use the strongsigned variant 'libphonenumber-csharp-portable', and the following code

```
using PhoneNumbers;
PhoneNumberUtil phoneUtil = PhoneNumberUtil.GetInstance();
```

I get the following error:

*Could not load file or assembly 'libphonenumber-csharp-portable, Version=4.10.0.62, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=ff8820ca68ac9de8' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.*

Apparently, the company that made the plugin (code) that I want to reuse, merged DLL's to include this third-party library.

Is this the way to go to use this package in Dynamics Plugins, or does anyone else have other recommandations on how to make this work? And, can onyone share how to properly merge DLL's, its benefits and risks?

Answer (score 0):

You should add it as a NuGet package(project>dependencies>packages no need to define with using), the version I used is 8.10.10 with .net6.
sample usage:

```
        var phoneNumberUtil = PhoneNumbers.PhoneNumberUtil.GetInstance();
        if (!PhoneNumbers.PhoneNumberUtil.IsViablePhoneNumber(input.From))
            return result;
        var phoneNumber = phoneNumberUtil.Parse(input.From, null);
        result.PhonePrefix = phoneNumber.CountryCode;
        result.Number = phoneNumber.NationalNumber;
        result.CountryCode = phoneNumberUtil.GetRegionCodeForCountryCode(phoneNumber.CountryCode);
```

Comment: Haven't tried it yet, just curious if you implemented it as a plugin in dynamics CRM as well, since for that purpose the solution (and package) needs to be strong signed.

Comment: It is already in use, it's a pretty effective library I think, it can cover %99 of the cases and save lots of time. It is also up-to-date and has lots of guidance in https://github.com/google/libphonenumber